# What amount of shingle overhang on a rake side is acceptable?

Tags: roofing, fascia

A contractor is telling me that his roofer always installs shingles with "this amount" of overhang, yet I am hard pressed to find similar installs in my neighborhood.  The box of shingles states 1/2" overhang with  a drip edge, 3/4" without.  The amount of overhang on my new screened in porch is 2".  I have read on forums that anything 1" and under is acceptable and typically passes inspection.  I live in Ohio; not in a high wind area.

I am done dealing with the contractor; it just not worth the energy or the arguing.  If I choose to fix this myself, is it worth trimming the shingles back to 1/2" or should I take my chances with heat causing the shingles to bend or wind ripping them off?

[image]

Comment: I agree with Lee Sam, but this is either a legal or aesthetic issue. Neither are realms we handle here. Consider your warranty and your appearance standards and do what you think best.

Comment: I am looking more for guidance on Risk, more than anything; based on knowledge or history.  "Am I making a mountain out of a molehill?"

Comment: Risk...??? Heck yes, but there’s a larger risk in doing nothing. If you get a leak, you’re on your own. Water is the one thing that will cause “other” problems if left unattended: dryrot, structural failures, mold, etc. and you’ll have no one to fix the problems. Did he get a Building Permit? Is it required? Call your local Building Code office and ask if your contractor is licensed to do business in your area.

Comment: The contractor has built sunrooms in this metropolitan area for 35 years.  I suspect they just get set in their ways.  Phone call today is sure to be pleasant.  If nothing else, I can snap a line and use snips when summer comes to trim them.

Answer (score 2):

A 2” overhang for shingles is excessive. Always follow the manufacturers installation instructions, because 1) performance is limited, 2) longevity is limited, and 3) warranty is voided.

1. shingles will sag and bend over time. This can create problems elsewhere, like tearing the underlayment, etc.
2. Shingles will wear out quicker because the shingles will fold at the roof line.
3. If you file a claim after a few years, a manufacturer’s representative will visit the site and void the claim. (If pieces of shingle blow off and break your neighbors windows, you’re liable.)

I find that when obvious things are done improperly, then other things are often done improperly too. I’d check the number of nails used per shingle, placement of nails from the top of the shingle, distance of first nail from edge of shingle, exposure of shingles, etc.

Btw, check several places on all sections of the roof. One roofer might do a great job where he’s working, but his assistant might be terrible.